# extension not working for me UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I can not use the Text Field make me an error on the next line[image]

[image]

Comment: Import UIkit only it will solve your error

Comment: Inglés por favor. [Stack overflow español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I work, but why in the code I have example works without having UIKit?

Answer (score 1):

just import UIKit like below

```
import UIKit
```

Comment: I work, but why in the code I have example works without having UIKit?

Comment: may be using bridge header@IsaM